# How to get the maximum amount of memory (RAM) consumed by a single query?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

I know this topic is pretty complex and involves a lot of different factors. Let's say I have several similar queries running at the same time. These queries involves only read operation and several ordering and windowing. If I'm not wrong, with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE (BUFFERS)` I can get the memory used by some operations like `ORDER BY`. I need to know how a single query impacts in order to calibrate (and kind of predict) the amount of queries I can run at the same time.

Is it possible to get the maximum amount (not the total amount) of memory used by a single query? Should I get it from the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output (which gives me only some memory usage infos) or there's a better way?

I'm using Postgres 9.5 and 9.6 on different Unix-like environments like Red Hat 6.7, Ubuntu 16.0.4 and macOS Sierra.

Comment: As each connection is a separate operating system process, you should be able to get that information by monitoring the process that belongs to the connection running that query. How you do that depends on your operating system.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I updated the question, but basically I work on Unix-like OSs. So I can't get that information simply looking at the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output?